# Dynamically injecting code in Twitter Bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

So, I've built a responsive site with Twitter Bootstrap. The problem is that I've done this using `visible-phone`, `visible-tablet`, and `visible-desktop`. This means that when someone views my source code, I have whole sections that are included twice or three times, in order to get around problems with differences in `span` amounts, or, for instance, because a carousel on the tablet should have 2 items, while on the desktop it should have 4.

I'm wondering if I'm doing this right. Should I be injecting (or adding? Not sure of the right name) code to the DOM dynamically using Javascript, based on screen size? Or should I be editing around with my custom, very simple .php files based on screen size? I don't know, and I can't find an answer about good practice anywhere. I've tried looking at sites I like for this, but I never find a javascript script that specifically adds stuff in this situation. Given, I'm not sure what I'd be looking for.

Any pointers?

Comment: Have you considered using @media queries in CSS?

Comment: Yes, I use those already. The issue is when I need to change the `span` amount because there are different amounts of elements in a `row-fluid` for different media. I don't want a inelegant solution, like manually changing percentages for all `span7 offset2`.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using script to dynamically add the content; as a fellow developer that just makes it less intuitive (in my opinion) and I always aim to produce intuitive code for the chap after me.

If your requirements state that a carousel should have four items on the desktop and two on mobile, then I think your solution is completely valid.